# Check duplicate username with parameterized query

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, ado.net

I want to check if username already exist in the database.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBCOnn"].ToString());
try
{
    con.Open();

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select client_id from tbl_client where client_name=@cname", con);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

   cmd.Parameters.Add("@cname", DbType.String).Value = usernm;

   int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if (i > 0)
       return true;
   else
       return false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("CheckExistingClient:" + ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

But here, `i` always giving as `-1`

What is the problem.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of affected rows and is used normally for insert-, update- or delete-statements. Use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with `COUNT` instead.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBCOnn"].ToString()))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(client_id) from tbl_client where client_name=@cname", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cname", DbType.String).Value = usernm;
    con.Open();
    int i = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return i > 0;
}
```

Here is a related answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269651/284240

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected by an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement. You're running a SELECT.

I find it's easier to "SELECT FROM Users where UserName=@cName" and run a standard Select.

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is meant for DML queries. You are not modifying and rows. So you get the result as -1.

You could use `select count(client_id) from tbl_client where client_name=@cname`

And get the count with `cmd.ExecuteScalar`