# Query is always returning -1 in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using following code to check if record exist.

```
SqlCommand check_Campaign_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Campaign_Summary  WHERE ([Compaign_Name] = @user) ", conn);
check_Campaign_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtBox_LastClick_Campaign.Text);

int CampaignExist = check_Campaign_Name.ExecuteNonQuery();

richTextBox1.Text = CampaignExist.ToString();
```

But I am always getting `-1` in the integer `CampaignExist`. Don't know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269548/executenonquery-for-select-sql-statement-returning-no-rows

Comment: are you sure your query itself is correct `SELECT * FROM Campaign_Summary  WHERE ([Compaign_Name] = @user)`? please test it first substituting real username at `@user`

Comment: You wrote `[Compaign_Name]` in the query, shouldn't that be `[Campaign_Name]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is not supposed to return the number of rows **SELECTED**, but the number of rows modified by an **INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE** command. You should use a `SqlDataReader` and check with its property `HasRows` or use an aggregate function like [COUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
(Probably the best choiche if you want to just retrieve the number of rows)

```
SqlCommand check_Campaign_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Campaign_Summary " + 
                                 "WHERE Compaign_Name = @user", conn);
check_Campaign_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtBox_LastClick_Campaign.Text);
int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(check_Campaign_Name.ExecuteScalar());
```

However, if you want only to know if the row exists or not, then the `COUNT` approach is considered less efficient than using the `EXISTS` statement.

```
string cmdText = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT Compaign_Name FROM Campaign_Summary 
                   WHERE Compaign_Name = @user)
                   SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT O";
SqlCommand check_Campaign_Name = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
int rowExists = Convert.ToInt32(check_Campaign_Name.ExecuteScalar());
```

This second approach just allows to know if there are rows that fits the WHERE statement or not.
So it is not exactly like `COUNT(*)` where you get the exact number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use executescalar method and count on query

```
SqlCommand check_Campaign_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Campaign_Summary  WHERE ([Compaign_Name] = @user) ", conn);
check_Campaign_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtBox_LastClick_Campaign.Text);

int CampaignExist = Convert.ToInt32(check_Campaign_Name.ExecuteScalar());

richTextBox1.Text = CampaignExist.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

As your query is a `SELECT` and not one of the mentioned `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE`s, it will always return `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Execute scalar [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
int CampaignExist = Convert.ToInt(check_Campaign_Name.ExecuteScalar());
```

---

```
SqlCommand check_Campaign_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Campaign_Summary  WHERE ([Compaign_Name] = @user) ", conn);
check_Campaign_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtBox_LastClick_Campaign.Text);

int CampaignExist = Convert.ToInt32(check_Campaign_Name.ExecuteScalar());

richTextBox1.Text = CampaignExist.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is not used to retrieve results

You can use one of the following methods:

1. `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` (I would prefer this)
2. `DataAdapter.Fill`