# Is SqlCommand in correct state after it's fail?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

I would like to create partially ordered parallel `SqlCommand` queue but I am not sure about one thing.

I need to consider situation when `SqlCommand` fails and it needs to be re-executed.

consider following code:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("adsf", someVal);
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
while(myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() <= 0) {
    log fail;
    wait some time;
}
```

Will be `SqlCommand` in correct state all tries? Or should I always create new `SqlCommand` and fill it with same parameters?

Comment: If nothing changes in the parameters you want to pass and the sql connection is also still open you can re execute the `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

Comment: The command object's state will be fine. The database state, not necessarily so.

Comment: Would you mind describing `partially ordered parallel SqlCommand queue`?

Comment: The return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` is `-1` only when the type of statement is `select` or rollback occurs. So the `while(myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() <= 0)` is not checking if `SqlCommand` fails. Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38060528/2946329

Comment: This can produce an infinite loop, you should add a counter at least. And you should check @RETURN_VALUE instead of the result of `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

To summarize, if none of your rows are affected by your stored procedure, you're going to return a value of 0

If you have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your stored procedure or a rollback occurs, you will always get a return value of -1

If you want to see if an error has occurred, you would need to put a try catch in your method. Obviously here I'm catching a generic exception. You would want to catch the specific exception and wrap the opening and the closing of your connection in a using statement to dispose of the connection when a failure occurs.

```
int retryCount = 0;
        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;")))
        {
            while (retryCount < 10)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (myCommand.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        myCommand.Connection.Open();
                    }

                    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    retryCount++;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: but here, you are creating new instances of SqlCommand every iteration.

Comment: I've edited the answer. The SQL command will be created once.